# JWplayer hide custom the logo after a number of seconds with the controlbar

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

In Flowplayer you can set the logo/bug image that overlays the image with the controlbar. Is this possible in JWplayer

Answer (score 1):

If you purchase a license for JW Player, you can eliminate the JW Player logo, or replace it with your own logo. For example: http://misterneutron.com/JW6videoLogo/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have commercial JWplayer. With this question I meant is it possible to hide the logo after a set number of seconds. I've updated the question.

Comment: I don't think so. It's either on for the entire video, or off for the entire video. I don't see anything in the API that allows you to control the duration and fade it out after a few seconds. But yeah, there should be that capability somewhere! Maybe Ethan will check in with some ideas (he works for JW Player).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be helpful for you.

Demo - http://www.pluginsbyethan.com/github/controlbarlogo.html

Instructions - https://github.com/emaxsaun/controlbarlogo

You still need to make a custom skin with the logo in the right endcap though:

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1412123-building-jw-player-skins
http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413071-skin-xml-reference

Comment: Better than nothing, but I would encourage JW Player to add an attribute to the standard setup that would allow the logo to remain on throughout the video, or to fade in and out with the control bar ("logofade: true or false"). I'd think that a lot of users would appreciate that.

Comment: Yeah, we are looking into some options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with jw player

```
    logo: {
    file: '/logo.png',
    link: 'http://www.phpflock.com/',
            hide:  'true',

},
```